# Replace a value in .dtsConfig using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis, config

I am using a find and replace statement, but I am getting an error on Get and Set content.

```
$GetChanges = Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\Users.....*.dtsConfig" | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace"bar","test" } 
$GetChanges | Set-Content -Path"C:\Users\......*.dtsConfig"
```

> ERROR: Set-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '-PathC'
>   does not exist.

Comment: Your question says `powershell` yet you tag it `CMD` a interactive user interface.

Comment: You cannot use wildcard characters like `*` when using `-LiteralPath`. Use `-Path` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$configlist = LS "C:\Users.....*.dtsConfig" -recurse

foreach($file in $configlist) {
    (Get-Content $file) -replace "bar","test" | Set-Content $file }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set-Content -Path"C:\Users\...` there should be a space between `-Path` and `"C:\Users\...`